# ProgressBar inside MaterialButton

Tags: android, material-design

I was looking at material design website when I got to this page about [circular progressbar](https://material.io/components/progress-indicators#circular-progress-indicators) and more precisely this [video](https://kstatic.googleusercontent.com/files/0a70f74ba7b198ba734b2003bbb9af016f61c7395a78c03375a30550dc5b5d8394c5314f705e69c517c9d9b1e58ff35339cee2154197c366696d3a9a55a3c25a)

I'd like to create a button like the one in the video but I don't see any documentation about this, and I don't know where to start

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zv9R5EcRKHM

Comment: useful link https://github.com/razir/ProgressButton

Comment: I'll take a look at both of your link :) thanks, I was looking for a button that can let me keep the material design attribute such as `drawableTop` etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to simply use:

```kotlin
val progress = CircularProgressDrawable(context).apply {
    setStyle(CircularProgressDrawable.DEFAULT)
    // do use setBounds if you need to 
    start()
}
myMaterialButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, progress, null, null)

// Do your stuff


//replace the image by the one you want
myMaterialButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, myDrawable, null, null)
```

Reference: [setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))

Answer (score 4):

You could also use `IndeterminateDrawable` from material progress indicator. I see the `CircularProgressDrawable` animation breaks in API level 25

```
private val progressDrawableBackward by lazy {
        val progressIndicatorSpec = CircularProgressIndicatorSpec(
            context,
            null,
            0,
            R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_CircularProgressIndicator_ExtraSmall
        )
        progressIndicatorSpec.indicatorColors =
            intArrayOf(progressColor)
        IndeterminateDrawable.createCircularDrawable(context, progressIndicatorSpec).apply {
            val size = (DRAWABLE_CENTER_RADIUS + DRAWABLE_STROKE_WIDTH ).toInt() * 2
            setBounds(0, 0, size, size)
            setVisible(true, true)
        }
    }
```