# Circular Progress Indicator inside Buttons, Android Material design

Tags: android, button, material-design, progress

I have just read that buttons (MaterialButton) ([progress indicator material design](https://material.io/components/progress-indicators#circular-progress-indicators)) in Material Design,  are able to hold a circular progress Indicator, as you can see in the attached picture

[image]

Bassically when you press the button remove text and show a progress indicator, but there is no clue about how to implement it, does anybody already deal with it?

it will be really appreciate any hint. Thanks

Comment: Refer this Link : https://medium.com/everything-full-stack/android-custom-button-with-centered-progress-indicator-ae329d0687d

Comment: Can be done using just MaterialButton, better than this kind of walkaround that have lots  of side effects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways this can be achieved is to create a Layout where you'll have a container and place both the button and the [CircularProgressIndicator](https://material.io/components/progress-indicators/android#circular-progress-indicators)

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/some_height"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_right"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_download"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/some_height"
            android:text="Download"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

     
    <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

Then you would just toggle the visibility of the progress bar and remove the text.

Another way is to use custom [animation drawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html). You would then add this to your button as a `drawableStart` or `drawableEnd` with some positioning, or perhaps even as a background.

3rd option would be, as per: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65180647/13187710

BTW, in the xml code above, you can substitute `Button` with `MaterialButton`.

Comment: yeahhh, this is what I have, but this is not good at all, there are thousands of caveats (like insets added by theme that make progress Indicator extends beyond buttons boundaries ),  for this material design do it within the same component MaterialButton,

Comment: There's no specific parameter for progress on the (material button)[https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton]. The second option, with animation, eliminates most of the issues you mention. I've added a 3rd option from another answer, here on SO.

Comment: Thanks, this 3rd option is better, but probably there is a better way to do it because it talks (docs: material design- progress indicator ) about "actionable icon", but good to know that someone asked the same one year before and still (probably ) there is no optimal approach. I ll try to research next days. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

With the **MaterialComponents** library you can use the **`IndeterminateDrawable`** class to create a `CircularProgressIndicator` and apply it to a `Button` or the icon in a `Button`:

```
   val spec =
        CircularProgressIndicatorSpec(this,  /*attrs=*/null, 0,
            com.google.android.material.R.style.Widget_Material3_CircularProgressIndicator_ExtraSmall)
    val progressIndicatorDrawable =
        IndeterminateDrawable.createCircularDrawable(this, spec)
    //...
    button.setOnClickListener {
        button.icon = progressIndicatorDrawable
    }
```

With:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/indicator_button"
    style="@style/Widget.Material3.Button.OutlinedButton.Icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:text="Button"/>
```

[image]

With **Compose** you can use something like:

```
 var progressIndicatorVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

 Button(
   onClick = {
     scope.launch {
         progressIndicatorVisible = true

         // Just for example
         delay(5000)
         progressIndicatorVisible = false
     }
   }, 
   modifier = Modifier.animateContentSize()){

     if (progressIndicatorVisible) {
         CircularProgressIndicator(
             color = White,
             strokeWidth = 2.dp,
             modifier = Modifier.size(15.dp)
         )
     }
     Text (
         "Button",
         modifier = Modifier.padding(start = if (progressIndicatorVisible) 8.dp else 0.dp)
     )
 }
```

[image]

Comment: How do we convert this into a deterministic indicator? Is there any way to show progress in this indicator?

Answer (score 3):

I have created an extension function which adds progressbar to any MaterialButton:

```
/**
* Shows indeterminate progress bar on this button in place of where icon would be.
* By default the tint of progress bar is the same as iconTint.
*
* @param tintColor (@ColorInt Int) Sets custom progress bar tint color.
*/
fun MaterialButton.showProgress(@ColorInt tintColor: Int = this.iconTint.defaultColor) {
    val spec = CircularProgressIndicatorSpec(context, null, 0,
        R.style.Widget_Material3_CircularProgressIndicator_ExtraSmall)

    spec.indicatorColors = intArrayOf(tintColor)

    val progressIndicatorDrawable =
        IndeterminateDrawable.createCircularDrawable(context, spec)

    this.icon = progressIndicatorDrawable
}
```